# curl_easy_perform: Couldn't resolve host name

Tags: c++, libcurl

I'm having a bit of an odd issue with `libcurl` - it's refusing to resolve a particular URL, returning the error message "Couldn't resolve host name." It has no issues resolving other hosts. I suspect the reason is that the URL which fails returns a 302 redirect, but I've set appropriate options for it to be followed.

The URL in question: http://servermods.cursecdn.com/files/922/48/worldedit-bukkit-6.1.3.jar

The relevant code:

```
CURL* curl;
FILE* data;
std::string url;

// ...

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FILE, data);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

Comment: A complete program we can compile would be helpful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`libcurl` expects a `char*` for `CURLOPT_URL`. My code was passing a `string`. This essentially causes the library to misinterpret the string and fail to resolve the host.

Comment: Surely the compiler threw some huge warning about that?

Comment: No, `curl_easy_setopt` expects a vararg of unspecified type, so the compiler apparently doesn't know better than to blindly accept it.